# Download all of today's stackexchange with wget

Tags: wget

Lets say that I want to recursively download all of today's posts on stackexchange as well as any wikipedia articles that they link to.

```
 wget -kprcH -l 4 -t 3 stackexchange.com
```

is not a good option, as it will go to a lot of other foreign sites other than wikipedia and stackexchange. If I use

```
wget -kprcH -l 4 -t 3 -D *stackexchange.com,*overflow.com,*overflow.net,*wikipedia.org stackexchange.com
```

I end up downloading one and only one page, "stackexchange.com"

What command should I use to download all of today's stackexchange and any wikipedia links that it might include without downloading a large amount of unwanted materials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "*" (asterisk) in front of the sites.  I tried this and it downloaded stackexchange and only the index.html file of Wikipedia.com without the content!

Comment: I don't know if this will work out as intended at the end, but it seems to be working correctly at the moment. I'll try to update with results, but for now I think that this is the correct answer. However, I can not mark it correct for another 2 minutes.